# Mysql 1050 Error "Table already exists" when in fact, it does not

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1146, mysql-error-1050

I'm adding this table:

```
CREATE TABLE contenttype (
        contenttypeid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        class VARBINARY(50) NOT NULL,
        packageid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        canplace ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        cansearch ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        cantag ENUM('0','1') DEFAULT '0',
        canattach ENUM('0','1') DEFAULT '0',
        isaggregator ENUM('0', '1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        PRIMARY KEY (contenttypeid),
        UNIQUE KEY packageclass (packageid, class)
);
```

And I get a 1050 "table already exists"

But the table does NOT exist. Any ideas?

EDIT: more details because everyone seems to not believe me :)

```
DESCRIBE contenttype
```

yields:

> 1146 - Table 'gunzfact_vbforumdb.contenttype' doesn't exist

and

```
CREATE TABLE gunzfact_vbforumdb.contenttype(
contenttypeid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
class VARBINARY( 50 ) NOT NULL ,
packageid INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
canplace ENUM( '0', '1' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
cansearch ENUM( '0', '1' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
cantag ENUM( '0', '1' ) DEFAULT '0',
canattach ENUM( '0', '1' ) DEFAULT '0',
isaggregator ENUM( '0', '1' ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY ( contenttypeid ) ,
```

Yields:

> 1050 - Table 'contenttype' already exists

Comment: How do you determine that it doesn't already exist?

Comment: Are you in the database you intend to create the table in? Also, try running `DESCRIBE contenttype` and see if it does in fact exist.

Comment: What makes you so sure that it does not exist?

Comment: Check my edited post. I'm not an idiot :) It definitely does not exist.

Comment: I would recommend to try the steps mentioned in the [blog](https://twindb.com/resolving-error-1050-42s01-at-line-1-table-already-exists/) shared in this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26023606/416369) post.

Comment: After suffering through this problem with a WP migration, where I exported the MySQL database from the production server, and tried importing the db on my local machine, I discovered that the SQL had "doubled up" in my db export sql for some reason. So, in other words, my sql was trying to create the same table twice in the same import file / SQL, even though when I refreshed it didn't show up. I figured out to copy and paste only up to where the 2nd table wasn't trying to be created.

Comment: I face same error while migrating a very large database from local to production so what I did 
I created a new database on production with a same name
then I move local database files *.ibd and *.frm to production via rsync

and then I face same issue what you are facing

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Sounds like you have [Schroedinger's table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat)...

Seriously now, you probably have a broken table. Try:

- `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contenttype`
- `REPAIR TABLE contenttype`
- If you have sufficient permissions, delete the data files (in /mysql/data/db_name)

Comment: > REPAIR TABLE contenttype USE_FRM


yields


gunzfact_vbforumdb.contenttype  repair  Error  Can't open table
gunzfact_vbforumdb.contenttype  repair  status  Operation failed


So we're getting closer but still no resolution. I dont know if the data is necessary in the table, is there any other way to fix it? I ran a myisamchk with no luck as well.

Comment: Can access *.myi, *.myd, *.frm files for the tables?

Comment: @Citizen Those are the actual files where table data and structure information are stored. They are usually somewhere in the mysql dir.

Comment: Just a heads up to anyone else, the table did exist but was totally borked. Nothing would detect it but I could drop the table.

Comment: I recently had this problem as well. This post helped me solve it. However, doing a DROP TABLE IF EXISTS followed by a REPAIR TABLE on the same table caused an error because of calling a repair on a nonexistent table. Only doing the DROP TABLE IF EXISTS seemed to work for me.

Comment: don't forget to restart ur SQL services.

Comment: I had a silly issue. I was importing tables from a file, and gave the same error. As the file was big, around 2GB, I didn't opened it. but later checked the file and observed that it had a `use otherdb` statement at the top. Hope it helps someone

Comment: I love when ancient answer still save lives! +1

Comment: I get this :`Note: #1051 Unknown table 'phpmyadmin.contenttype'`

Comment: I ran into this issue when dropping a really large table, ~ 400GB. Only restarting the mariadb instance worked. Not sure if this is a bug related to mariadb specifically or both mariadb and mysql.

Answer (score 36):

from MySQL Log:

```
InnoDB: You can drop the orphaned table inside InnoDB by
InnoDB: creating an InnoDB table with the same name in another
InnoDB: database and copying the .frm file to the current database.
InnoDB: Then MySQL thinks the table exists, and DROP TABLE will
InnoDB: succeed.
```

Comment: It worked for me. But Have to repeat for all tables in my database.

Comment: yeah, looks like this can be caused by changing an InnoDB table to MyISAM using ALTER TABLE ** engine MyISAM.  mysqlhotcopy might have be involved in creating my issue as well, as it does not work with InnoDB tables and this one may have still been InnoDB when I first executed the command.

Comment: Does not work for me... Table still does not exist even though I now have valid *.frm and *.ibd files.

Comment: ensure that mysql has permissions to #sql-ibXXX.frm file

Comment: Thank you so much... Never got this from the log but it actually worked.

Comment: Holy Moly! Couldn't get rid of a `Table already exists` error when creating my table even by executing a `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` right before. The workaround of creating a dummy table with the same name (and dummy columns) and using the .frm and .ibd worked like a charm!
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I created table in the same database but with slightly different name (added '2' at the end), then renamed .frm file to original table name. Then I was able to drop orphaned table.

Comment: This does not work for me.
While you CAN use "DROP TABLE" when putting a .frm file there the problem itself persists. 
Innodb keeps bitching about an existing table when you create a similar named one in that db even if you just "dropped" it using that method.

Answer (score 18):

You may need to flush the table cache.  For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tablename` ;
FLUSH TABLES `tablename` ; /* or exclude `tablename` to flush all tables */
CREATE TABLE `tablename` ...
```

Comment: thanks, you save me, some how my schema got corupt (i culd't drop it) so i delete all files but keep getting same error until i tried this

Comment: don't forget to restart your SQL services.

Comment: Working for me!

Answer (score 16):

I got this same error, and REPAIR TABLE (from @NullUserException's answer) didn't help.

I eventually found [this solution](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=30513#c174255):

```
sudo mysqladmin flush-tables
```

For me, without the `sudo`, I got the following error:

```
mysqladmin: refresh failed; error: 'Access denied; you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation'
```

(Running on OS X 10.6)

Comment: Thanks, `sudo mysqladmin flush-tables` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 5):

Same problem occurred with me while creating a view.
The view was present earlier then due to some changes it got removed But when I tried to add it again it was showing me "view already exists" error message.

**Solution**:

You can do one thing manually.

1. Go to the MySQL folder where you have installed it
2. Go to the data folder inside it.
3. Choose your database and go inside it.
4. Data base creates ".frm" format files.
5. delete the particular table's file.
6. Now create the table again.

It will create the table successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem on Win7 in Sql Maestro for MySql 12.3. Enormously irritating, a show stopper in fact. Nothing helped, not even dropping and recreating the database. I have this same setup on XP and it works there, so after reading your answers about permissions I realized that it must be Win7 permissions related. So I ran MySql as administrator and even though Sql Maestro was run normally, the error disappeared. So it must have been a permissions issue between Win7 and MySql.

Answer (score 4):

I've been fighting with this all day:  I have a Perl script that builds a set of tables by first doing a `DROP IF EXISTS ...` on them and then `CREATE`ing them.  The `DROP` succeeded, but on `CREATE` I got this error message:  `table already exists`

I finally got to the bottom of it:  The new version of MySQL that I'm using has a default engine of InnoDB ("show engine \G;")  I changed it in the my.cnf file to default to MyISAM, re-started MySQL, and now I no longer get the "table already exists" error.

Comment: didn't work for me. Changed global MySQL engine from InnoDB to MyISAM - same issue for exists/doesn't exist. MySQL server running on Windows 2003.

Answer (score 4):

Encountering the same problem (create InnoDB table) this is what finally worked for me:

```
DROP DATABASE `having_issues`;
```

I checked on a file basis, permissions, tried to REPAIR and FLUSH but nothing worked.

So if this is an option, move all working tables to another DATABASE, drop the old one *(you might have to manually remove any files from the database folder before the drop to work)*, rename the new one, and you 'should' be back on your way. Apparently, whatever gets 'cached' using InnoDB is dropped along with the original database.

Comment: I have also worked through all the other ideas I saw here, but this was the only one that worked. Apparently, the database in current MySQL versions (at least on my WAMPP installation) has some information cached that made it impossible to just fix it by removing the orphaned `ibd` file. Flush tables, REPAIR TABLE etc did not work either.

Answer (score 4):

You won´t believe me! I´ve just removed a comment block from my .sql file and now it works.

```
CREATE DATABASE  IF NOT EXISTS `issga` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `issga`;
--
-- Table structure for table `protocolo`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS protocolo;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
 CREATE TABLE protocolo (
  `idProtocolo` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tipo` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estado` int(2) DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idProtocolo`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=142 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
 /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `protocolo`
--

LOCK TABLES protocolo WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE protocolo DISABLE KEYS */;
/* INSERT INTO `protocolo` VALUES () */
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE protocolo ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The deleted comment block was this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `protocolo`
--
```

I´ve left the problematic table alone in the same .sql file. After that I´ve removed comments, the only code was left, and the error disappears.

Answer (score 4):

I am struggling with the same issue.  I cannot create a table, even though it does not exist. I tried all the above solutions with no success.

My solution was to delete the files `ib_logfil0`, `ib_logfile1`, `ibdata1`, and `auto.cnf` from the data folder of MySQL; make sure to stop the MySQL service first before deleting these files.

Then after restarting the service, MySQL recreated these files and I was able to run a backup script were all my `CREATE`s were stored (a sqldump file).

Comment: This worked for me, along with dropping the table initially. Thanks :)

Comment: I have a full backup of MySQL folder (usr/local/var/mysql), after reinstall mysql (brew), when I try to replace that backup folder, my old all database showing not exist :( can you please help me how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered this problem where trying to Create a table said it already exists and Dropping the table said it didn't exist.

I did "FLUSH TABLES" and it cleared the problem.

Answer (score 2):

First check if you are in the right database `USE yourDB` and try `Select * from contenttype` just to see what is it and if it exists really...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem at Mac OS X and MySQL 5.1.40. I used eclipse to edit my SQL script and than I tried MySQLWorkbench 5.2.28. Probably it converted newline characters to Mac format. I had no idea about what's wrong with my script until I commented out the first line in file. After this this script was interpreted by mysql as a one single comment. I used build-in TextEdit Mac application to fix this. After line-breaks was converted to the correct format, the error 1050 gone.

**Update for Eclipse users:**

To set up default ending for new files created, across the entire workspace:

> Window -> Preferences -> General ->
>   Workspace -> New text file line
>   delimiter.

To convert existing files, open file for editing and for the currently edited file, go to the menu:

> File -> Convert Line Delimiters To

Answer (score 2):

I had this same case. The problem ended up being permissions on the parent directory.

I had been copying files in and out of mysql during testing.

```
drwx------   3 _mysql  wheel
```

was not enough, needed to be:

```
-rw-rw----   3 _mysql  wheel
```

Sorry to resurrect.

Answer (score 2):

I was having huge issues with Error 1050 and 150.

The problem, for me was that I was trying to add a constraint with `ON DELETE SET NULL` as one of the conditions.

Changing to `ON DELETE NO ACTION` allowed me to add the required FK constraints.

Unfortunately the MySql error messages are utterly unhelpful so I had to find this solution iteratively and with the help of the answers to the question above.

Answer (score 2):

Your disk also might just be full. (just had that)

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted you. I'm glad to see more responses for other things that it could be for someone finding this on Google.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and it looks like the Database name was case sensitive. My Database is called:

```
Mydatabase
```

Whilst my script included

```
USE mydatabase
```

Once I changed the database name to the correct case it all seemed to work. Using MYSQL Workbench on MAC OSX

Answer (score 1):

This problem also occurs if a 'view' (imaginary table) exists in database as same name as our new table name.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I found this to be an issue with InnoDB; I never discovered what the actual problem was, but creating as a MyISAM allowed it to build

Comment: As a response to jmadsen (maybe a bit late....) I had the same problem and the cause was that the table was created within InnoDB storage and the correspondending .frm file was deleted outside MySQL. So I restored the .frm file from a backup and I was able to repair / delete / recreate the table. Regards,
Roland Leurs

Answer (score 1):

My CREATE statement was part of staging env dump.

I did try everything that has been mentioned above. I DID NOT get solution. However my path to  redemption was:

1. I stumble upon the fact that (one of many in) the CREATE statement did get through when I rectified the database name case sensitivity. This clicked something. I repeated the same for the other tables.
2. However a new error came into the scene. The straight quotes for 'comments'  were throwing syntax error. I was shocked. replaced them but the new error started popping up. Finally i knew the solution.

SOLUTION: The dump i was using might have been from a different version of MySql. I got permission to connect to the staging MYsql using the local(installed on my machine) mysql workbench. I did not rdp into the staging server to login to staging mysql workbench. Created a dump from there. Ran the dump and it worked like a sweet.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was caused when using a filesystem copy of the mysql database directory instead of mysqldump.  I have some very large tables, mostly MyISAM and a few InnoDB cache tables and it is not practical to mysqldump the data.  Since we are still running MyISAM, XtraBackup is not an option.

The same symptoms as above happened to me.  The table is not there, there are no files in the directory that pertain to the table, yet it cannot be created because MySQL thinks its there.  Drop table says it's not there, create table says it is.

The problem occurred on two machines, both were fixed by copying backups.  However, I noticed that in my backup that there was a .MYD and .MYI file, even though I was under the impression that these files are not used for InnoDB.  The .MYD and .MYI files had an owner of root, while the .frm was owned by mysql.

If you copy from backup, check the file permissions.  Flush tables might work, but I opted to shut down and restart the database.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

gosh, i had the same problem with `osCommerce` install script until i figured out the mysql system has many databases and the `create table` query copies itself into each one and thus droping only the working table on active db didnt help, i had to drop the table from all dbs

Answer (score 1):

Was trying to import a backup sql file but was getting the error; 1050 "Table already exists"

My setup was:

- Windows 7
- Mysql  5.5.16

Solution:

1. Changed the server engine from InnoDB to MyISAM
2. Using phpMyAdmin Deleted the database I was trying to import to
3. Restarted the mysql service
4. Tried the re-importation and it worked

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that there was a view with the same name as my table, so I had to drop the view to allow the import to continue.

```
drop view `my-view-that-has-same-name-as-table`;
```

An automated solution that worked for me is to replace the normal drop table with this sed during the dump to also drop any views that might exist:

```
mysqldump my-db \
| sed -E 's/^DROP TABLE IF EXISTS(.+)$/\0 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS\1/g' \
| mysql my-other-db
```

Or if you would rather print to a file for backup

```
mysqldump my-db \
| sed -E 's/^DROP TABLE IF EXISTS(.+)$/\0 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS\1/g' \
> my-db.dump.sql
```

Or if you received the dumped file and you are importing it to your db

```
cat my-db.dump.sql \
| sed -E 's/^DROP TABLE IF EXISTS(.+)$/\0 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS\1/g' \
| mysql my-other-db
```

You get the idea

Note: it is important that you add the `^` at the beginning of the replacement regex, because there are other types of `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` commands in dumps that you don't want to touch.

You go from having something like this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `my_table`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
...
```

To having something like this:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `my_table`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_table`; DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `my_table`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the same error but I knew the table already existed and wanted to add to it. I'm adding my answer as this question comes up as no.1 for me on google when looking for the same error but for a slightly different scenario. Basically I needed to tick

"Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER statement"

And this solved the error for me.

Comment: do you mean "needed to tick" in the permissions?

Comment: In PHPmyAdmin when choosing to do a custom export of the database under the section Object creation options, there is a checkbox for "Add DROP TABLE / VIEW / PROCEDURE / FUNCTION / EVENT / TRIGGER statement"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error importing a .sql dump for a Magento eCommerce on a new empty database. I've tried some of the solutions above but none worked, I've fixed the problem changing the way the dump was created.

Adding [single transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) when creating the dump fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must delete the files inside the folder of your database in mysql/data/yourdatabase because even though you've deleted/drop table in phpmyadmin the folder's files did not delete.[image: picture is for reference of what to delete]

Answer (score 0):

Needed to a mixed of everything to solve my problem, in this order:

**Atention: this solution will erase your broken table's data**

1. Create temporary db (`db_temp`);
2. Create a table with SAME NAME and schema in `db_temp` (`twin_table`)
3. Move to `db_temp` table's folder -> `cd /var/lib/mysql/db_temp/`
4. Copy desired table .frm to `production_db` -> `cp twin_table.frm ../production_db/`
5. Change permissions of .ibd and .frm files in `production_db`-> `chmod a+rw twin_table.frm` and `chmod a+rw twin_table.ibd`
6. Access mysql terminal -> `mysql -u root -p`
7. Use production_db -> `USE production_db;`
8. Flush tables -> `FLUSH TABLES;`
9. Drop broken table -> `DROP TABLE twin_table;`
10. re-create table -> `CREATE TABLE twin_table (table config goes here);`