# Creating tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1146

I created a table license_serial in my "database_name". But when I tried creating a second table named license, it says that it already exists.
Why is that ? My database contains only a license_serial.frm and a db.opt.

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+---------------------+
| Tables_in_mobilemp3 |
+---------------------+
| license_serial      |
+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from license;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mobilemp3.license' doesn't exist
```

Creating the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE `license` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`serial_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`uid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
`active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`first_seen` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`last_seen` timestamp NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `serial_uid` (`serial_id`,`uid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

gives the following error message:

```
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'mobilemp3.license' already exists
```

EDIT:

And the solution is this(in this order):

```
drop database databasename;
create database databasename;
use databasename;
```

Comment: show us the output of the command SHOW TABLES

Comment: I read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302476/mysql-1050-error-table-already-exists-when-in-fact-it-does-not but I don't get the solution, what files shoudl i delete ?

Comment: Show us how you "create the second table"

Comment: you dont create a table by creating a file, you write a sql

Comment: What is the exact error message you get when running the CREATE TABLE?

Comment: @lbu: what do you mean ? sorry I'm a beginner

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`mobilemp3`.`license`' already exists

Comment: There must be something you are not telling us. If the posted result from `show tables` is correct, then that error should not happen. Are you sure you are connected to the same server and database when running the CREATE TABLE

Comment: yes, i typed use mobilemp3; before calling create table too

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: check the link i posted in my first answer , you should see the same thing happend to that guy to, and nobody belive him:) but i did what that post said, and still the same

Comment: I can reproduce a similar issue - I'd suggest you check the various system log files - it's highly likely that MySQL has hit some sort of problem --- e.g. I see MySQL leading effectively a oops message with hopefully helpful things for logging a bug on bugs.mysql.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, is that the table was created e.g. by root and the user you are using does not have access to that table. In that case you cannot select from it (not sure if it would be filtered out in the show tables command though)

Log in as root to that database and check if that table exists.

Comment: if I try to create it using MySQL Querry Browser, it says: Table 'mobilemp3.license' doesn't exist   very strange

Comment: @vBx: What does `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables` give you when run as roo?

Comment: A select cannot return a "file". Just check if the table license appears in the result.

Comment: @vBx: deleting everything and starting from a clean database is not really a solution. Would have been interesing to find out the *real* cause of this problem.

Comment: I just wanted the database created, so for me it is a solution :)