# Conversion myisam to innodb gives "table already exists" on (almost) all tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, alter

It should have been easy... I have a database with about 20 tables in it, all in MyISAM. I wanted to convert them to InnoSB, so I executed:

```
alter table xxxx engine = InnoDB;
```

As a result I get

```
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table './yyy/xxx' already exists
```

I tried several of the tables, and thought it would happen with all, till
I hit two tables which got converted correctly. 
A SHOW TABLE STATUS confirmed the correct conversion. Strangely enough
several of the other tables had a very similar or equal structure but
didn't convert.

MySQL Version is 5.5.27... I tried through phpMyAdmin, and directly
through mysql commands. Same result.

Note: I had found the thread indicated below, and here are some of the tests:
- I did mysqlchk the table - it's ok. 
- The DROP TABLE suggested works, table disappears,
- REPAIR TABLE then reports it can't file the table (as is logical). 
- If I re-instate the table from a backup, Same error re-appears.

Could a parallel InnoDB table exist, which I can't see?

Comment: Maybe take a look at some of the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302476/mysql-1050-error-table-already-exists-when-in-fact-it-does-not

Comment: Yes, of course I read that thread. I did several of the proposed solutions, and also checked many of the 'foreign key' references I found in other mails. No all of the solutions are really 'testable' here, as I am trying to convert, so I cannot really delete the original database. I added a couple to the original message.

Comment: I suppose you could create new tables in a different schema and copy the data with INSERT .. SELECT. I don't really have any good ideas about what's causing your error. Permissions issue on the table files...?

Answer (score 1):

To be fair, the solution is inspired by one of the last entries in the thread indicated by #takteek.

Deciding the problem was probably a duplicate table (the original in MyISAM, and probably some tables in InnoDB, left over from previous experiments), I decided to use the sledgehammer approach:

- DROP DATABASE yyy;
- Reinstated the MyISAM database from a backup (Stopped the server, untarred the
  database archive, restarted the server).
- then did the ALTER TABLES xxx ENGINE  InniDB on each table

I generally dislike such dramatic solutions, as they give the feeling there are tools (or knowledge) lacking. In this case, I couldn't find a way to confirm or confirm the spurious tables, or a way to selectively drop those tables.

Anyway, maybe this helps someone.