# Why does MySQL fail with ERROR 156 "Table already exists" when trying to create an index?

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to add uniqueness constraint on an existing table by creating an index.

Here's the existing table (I've tried to make mysql's output a bit more readable):

```
mysql> show create table profile_status;

| Table          | Create Table
| profile_status | CREATE TABLE `profile_status` (
                       `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                       `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                       `proxy_profile_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                        KEY `user_id_refs_user_id` (`user_id`),
                        KEY `profile_status` (`proxy_profile_id`),
                        CONSTRAINT `proxy_profile_id_refs_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`proxy_profile_id`) REFERENCES `profile_userprofile` (`user_id`),
                        CONSTRAINT `user_id_refs_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `profile_userprofile` (`user_id`)
                    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here's what happens when I attempt to create the index:

```
mysql> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `profile_status_unique` ON `profile_status` (`user_id`);
ERROR 156 (HY000): Table 'project.profile_status#1' already exists
```

My first suspicion is that the error message is misleading, and in fact MySQL is in fact refusing to create a second index on the user_id column, since there's already a non-unique key there.  So I tried dropping that key first (along with the associated foreign key constraint):

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE profile_status DROP FOREIGN KEY user_id_refs_user_id;
Query OK, 112 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 112  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> ALTER TABLE profile_status DROP KEY user_id_refs_user_id;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> show create table profile_status;

| Table          | Create Table
| profile_status | CREATE TABLE `profile_status` (
                       `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
                       `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                       `proxy_profile_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
                        KEY `profile_status` (`proxy_profile_id`),
                        CONSTRAINT `proxy_profile_id_refs_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`proxy_profile_id`) REFERENCES `profile_userprofile` (`user_id`),
                    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `profile_status_unique` ON `profile_status` (`user_id`);
ERROR 156 (HY000): Table 'project.profile_status#1' already exists
```

Same result.  At this point I'm thoroughly stumped, and I'd really appreciate some help.  Worst case, I could create a temporary table with the correct constraints and copy over the data, but I'd like to understand this problem fully.

Thanks in advance.  Here's the MySQL details:

```
mysql> show variables like '%version%';
| Variable_name           | Value
| innodb_version          | 1.1.8
| protocol_version        | 10
| version                 | 5.5.28-1
| version_comment         | (Debian)
| version_compile_machine | i686
| version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This is a really wild guess: try `DROP TEMPORARY TABLE playmeet.profile_status#1` (with backticks around the name - can't use those in comments).

Comment: Thanks, but no dice: ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'project.profile_status#1'

Comment: @vatev You can use them, it's just annoying: `\\``.

Comment: Strange cause it works fine in SQLFIDDLE : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd007/0 ... but I have to remove the `CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY`

Comment: Have a look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302476/mysql-1050-error-table-already-exists-when-in-fact-it-does-not

Comment: @Fabien-TheSolution: Interesting.  On sqlfiddle, I can run all the queries as-is, including the foreign key constraints, if I create a dummy user_profile table: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/51d6e

Comment: May be something corrupt in your DB...Did you looked at the link I provided ? There is some good ideas there...

Comment: It also works if I try it on a new table with the same schema, in the same database.  So I suppose this implies that there's something elsewhere in the state of the db that's causing the problem...

Comment: @Fabien-TheSolution: I did check your link, thank you.  But REPAIR TABLE doesn't work on InnoDB tables, and mysqladmin flush-tables didn't do anything either.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35615/discussion-between-nephtes-and-fabien-thesolution)

Answer (score 0):

Check if 'project' directory in your MySQL data directory does not contain any unwanted/temporary files. Remove them if you see files starting with something like ? or #. Also check if file with name 'profile_status#1' exists and remove it.

Then login to MySQL, execute FLUSH TABLES (even if there were no unwanted files in the above step) and try altering the table again.