# Error 156: table already exists when adding a primary key

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following statement `ALTER TABLE my_tbl  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id );` to add a primary key to an existing MySQL table. In reply I'm getting the error:

> Error 156 : Table 'db_name.my_tbl#1' already exists.

I checked and the table has no duplicate id entries, and if I do something like `DROP TABLE my_tbl#1` then the original table (my_tbl) is deleted. It's perhaps interesting to note that my_tbl was created by `Create Table my_tbl SELECT id, ... FROM tmp_tbl` (where tmp_tbl is a temporary table).

Anyone has an idea what's going on here?

Update: there seems to be some kind of an orphaned table situation here. I tried the suggestions in the answers below, but in my case they did not resolve the problem. I finally used a workaround: I created a table with a different name (e.g. my_tbl_new) , copied the information to this table and added to it the primary key. I Then deleted the original table and renamed the new one back to my_tbl.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:-

```
ALTER TABLE my_tbl  DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(id,id);
```

or try this:-

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE  CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    AND TABLE_NAME = '[my_tbl]' 
    AND TABLE_SCHEMA ='dbo' )
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_tbl] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  ([ID])
END
```

or try to flush the table like this:-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `my_tbl` ;
   FLUSH TABLES `my_tbl` ; 
   CREATE TABLE `my_tbl` ...
```

Comment: Tried it, but the table doesn't have a primary key. I'm getting the error: Can't DROP 'PRIMARY'; check that column/key exists

Comment: @hillel:- Updated my answer with all the possible solutions. Check it!!

Comment: @Rahul: same error "Table already exists" when trying the second option. Trying repair gives me "The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair" (this is an innoDB table), also using mysqladmin flush-tables didn't change the error.

Comment: @hillel:- Check this out:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302476/mysql-1050-error-table-already-exists-when-in-fact-it-does-not

Comment: Your SQL to check the constraint existance seems to be for SQL Server, not for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable` ;
FLUSH TABLES `mytable` ; 
CREATE TABLE `mytable` ...
```

Also it might be a permission issue.

Comment: Tried it but still getting the same output (error 156: table db_name.my_tbl#1 already exists.)

Comment: @hillel What engine are you using?

Comment: it's innoDB (I'm using MySQL on Amazon RDS if that matters)

Comment: @hillel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302476/mysql-1050-error-table-already-exists-when-in-fact-it-does-not

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while trying to alter indexes, through SQLyog, when my database name contained "-" chars. So I renamed the database to not have them and then it worked just fine.

(Since there's no direct way to rename a DB, I had to copy it to a new one, with correct name)