# unable to alter table, Table 'xxx/#sql-ib265' already exists

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table y in database xxx which I attempted to change compression type before using

```
    alter table y row_format=compressed key_block_size=8
```

the process stopped half way.  I removed temp file '#sql-ib265.frm and #sql-ib265' in mysql lib directory and restarted the server. However
Now when I attempt the alter table y (with the same command above) again I get error.

```
    ERROR 1050 (42S01) at line 1: Table 'xxx/#sql-ib265' already exists
```

I can't drop table 'xxx/#sql-ib265' because it can't be found.
what should I do?

Edit
Solution:

```
I ended up dropping the old database and recreate the database.
```

Comment: What engine are you using for the table?innodb?

Comment: @Nishant Shrivastava: yes innodb

Comment: Have you tried dropping the table y? Try to get rid of the table y.. once it is dropped, the innodb dictionary should get cleaned up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to restart mysql client with the --skip-auto-rehash option and try DROP TABLE again.

If above does not work, try this from MySQL Manual:

You have a corrupt innodb data dictionary..

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html

Problem with Temporary Table

If MySQL crashes in the middle of an ALTER TABLE operation, you may end up with an orphaned temporary table inside the InnoDB tablespace. Using the Table Monitor, you can see listed a table with a name that begins with #sql-. You can perform SQL statements on tables whose name contains the character “#” if you enclose the name within backticks. Thus, you can drop such an orphaned table like any other orphaned table using the method described earlier. To copy or rename a file in the Unix shell, you need to put the file name in double quotation marks if the file name contains “#”.

Comment: I tried all of them. didn't work.  drop table with tick `#sql-ib265` says the table doesn't exist.  show table didn't show the table.

Comment: try restarting mysql with the following in your my.cnf .. make sure you have necesaary things backed up .. in case things get messed up further..  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html 
[mysqld]
innodb_force_recovery = 1

Comment: May be as a last option.. backup your DB and try dropping the entire DB .. then restore your data .. and create the table you need ?

Comment: Btw.. what is your table name ?? isn't it XXX .. so should you not be trying to Drop xxx ?

Comment: my table name is y, database name is xxx, the temp table that somehow got created is #sql-ib265, I've edited the question for clarity

Comment: Try dropping table y and not the #sql-ib265 .. this sql-ib265 would be an incorrect reference in the innodb data dictionary which you want to get rid of... if you are able to delete the table y, all bad references for table y would automatically get deleted. I hope you have a backup of the data of the table y... if not... try to take a dump once before you drop it.

Comment: table y is very large and could take weeks to recreate.  Is there a way to remove the reference sql-ib265?

Comment: CREATE TABLE `rsql-id_recover_innodb_tmp_table`(...) TYPE=InnoDB;
The table definition must be similar to that of the temporary table. Now copy the frm file created into the file (#sql-ib265.frm) you deleted .. and then try the drop command...

Comment: after I did that and tries to drop the recover_innodb_tmp_table, it says table doesn't exist

Comment: you need to try to drop the `#sql-ib265.frm` table.. after you have copied the new frm to #sql-ib265.frm

Comment: i tried drop table `#sql-ib265`, it says table doesn't exist. I have #sql-ib265.frm and #sql-ib265.ibd in the mysql db dir

Comment: There is important information in the MySQL documentation link in this answer. See the sections called `Orphan Intermediate Tables` and `Orphan Temporary Tables`

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to fix this problem.

1. As other answer suggests, [official MySQL documentation suggests](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html) to drop a specially crafted table. But please note in versions >= 5.1 you need to prefix table name with `#mysql50#`.
2. Move (use `RENAME TO`) all good tables to a temporary database, drop&recreate the original one and then move the tables back. See [a blog post](https://twindb.com/resolving-error-1050-42s01-at-line-1-table-already-exists/) for details.

Comment: I manually tried the steps mentioned in the [blog](https://twindb.com/resolving-error-1050-42s01-at-line-1-table-already-exists/) and it worked!!!

Comment: Good. Don't forget to +1 ;)

Answer (score 0):

in additional I'm loging in with root to do the recover job but failed. then i chown the .frm file to meet the owner of mysql service and succeed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still facing this problem, I have just followed the following steps to solve it, which (to me at least) seem far less daunting than other solutions:

1. Use `mysqldump` to back up the database with all its data.
2. Drop and recreate the database.
3. Reload the database and all its schema from the file generated in (1).

Because the orphaned tables are hidden anyway, they don't get backed up, so you end up with a database without them. I had all my procedures/functions scripted out anyway, so was able to restore them easily - if you don't, make sure you use the `--routines` parameter to dump those too.

My dump file was around 1.5GB for the database in question (so it's not small), and the whole thing was completed in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I fixed it by switching the order in which I dropped the tables at the beginning of the file:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_name;
```

This line is repeated for each table. Tables with foreign keys need to be deleted before the tables with the primary keys to which they point.