# Failing DDL and locked database

Tags: ddl, google-cloud-sql

Instance: skilled-tiger-296:db

One table became inaccessible with selects failing error 'Table doesn't exist'.
Attempts to drop table caused the same error.
Attempts to create table caused error 'Table exists already'.
Attempts to drop schema fail with internal error and disconnect from instance.

Forward-engineering schema with a new name helped for a couple days and now its failing again on the same table.

Problem 1: Lost table
Problem 2: cannot drop database (dbname: flow)

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have a corruption problem. Try running DROP TABLE IF EXISTS and REPAIR TABLE like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302476/mysql-1050-error-table-already-exists-when-in-fact-it-does-not). Also make sure in future you use InnoDB tables as these are much more robust.