# in mysql table exists, but it doesn't

Tags: mysql

A very strange error that i can't work out.  I can't create a table as mysql says it exists, even though I have explicitly tried to drop it.

```
mysql> drop table `wp881-2`.`trd_plans`;
ERROR 1051 (42S02): Unknown table 'wp881-2.trd_plans'
mysql> CREATE TABLE `wp881-2`.`trd_plans` ( `id` INT NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ERROR 1813 (HY000): Tablespace '`wp881-2`.`trd_plans`' exists.
```

To double check i've also run show tables; and the table doesn't exist there either.

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT:
This isn't a duplicate as far as I can tell because I tried the suggested solution of deleting orphaned files and while there was an extra .ibd file (which I deleted), when I tried to execute CREATE TABLE again still the same error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3302476/mysql-1050-error-table-already-exists-when-in-fact-it-does-not

Comment: CREATE TABLE `wp881-2`.`trd_plans` ( `id` INT(11) NOT NULL ) ENGINE = InnoDB;

Try this one.

Comment: maybe you drop the table, But the underline files in the system dodn't delete for some reasons.

Comment: Check whether you have any server cache or schema cache is involved. Most of the case there is schema cache on and will reflect after some hours.

Comment: Managed to solve the issue.  For anyone reading this, the solution for me was a combination of things: 1) delete extra .ibd tables; and then 2) mysqladmin flush-tables.