# I am getting error code 105 using create view

Tags: mysql, view, create-view

[![I am getting error code: 1050 (as you can see at from the output in the image) Table already exists, when it doesnt.  Can anyone help me with this?

The question reads: **Create a view called ‘computer_science_students’ for the SELECT query created under Index step** ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMkPU.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMkPU.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. How much effort would it have been to copy and paste this small amount of code into the question?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you have Schroedinger's table...

you probably have a broken table. Try:

Syntax
The syntax for the DROP VIEW statement in MySQL is:

DROP VIEW [IF EXISTS] view_name;
view_name - The name of the view that you wish to drop.
IF EXISTS - Optional. If you do not specify this clause and the VIEW does not exist, the DROP VIEW statement will return an error.

If you have sufficient permissions, delete the data files (in /mysql/data/db_name)

Comment: Don't just copy [someone else's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3302837/14853083) and post it here as your own. Flag this question as a duplicate, if it is indeed a duplicate.

Comment: even using drop statements it still outputs error 1050

Comment: Mysql thinks it does.  
FLUSH TABLES; /* Clears all tables from the table cache */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `MyDatabase`.`MyTableName`;
FLUSH TABLES;